# С++ wrapping lambda in another lambda inside a function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

Basically, I'm having this code:

```
struct Receiver {
    void receive(std::function<void()> f) {
        func_ = f;
    }
    std::function<void()> func_;
};

void pusher(Receiver& r) {
    auto wrapper=[&](std::function<void()> w) {
        r.receive([&]() {
            cout << "Before" << endl;   
            w();
            cout << "After" << endl;    
        });
    };


    wrapper([&]() {
        cout << "Original" << endl; 
    });
}

int main() {
    Receiver r;
    pusher(r);
    r.func_();
    return 0;
}
```

There's a class which stores std::function and we store a function into that class.
Function is created in a "wrapper" local lambda of another function.

The code prints "Before" and crashes.
If I put the whole code inside "pusher" into main(), then everything works.

I suspect the problem us that when r.receive() is called, it contains reference to "w" which is invalid after returning from "pusher".

But I need to pass a lambda to a receiver which is created by "decoration" with another lambda.

How do I properly (in general) decorate a lambda with a reference to some local lambda and pass it somewhere else?

Comment: You are capturing by reference in the second lambda, try capturing by value with [=] .

Comment: You need to either copy or move `w` into the lambda.(i.e `[w=move(w)]`)

Comment: @0x499602D2 that should be an answer

Comment: The `w` you are using inside your inner lambda function is a reference to the `w` parameter passed into the outer lambda function. That parameter is destroyed as soon as the outer lambda function exits and the inner lambda function then has a dangling reference.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You cannot move into the lambda in C++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The by-reference capture `[&]` causes the lambda to hold a reference to `w` after it has expired. You either need to copy `w` `[=]` or move it into the lambda (C++14):

```
r.receive([w=std::move(w)]() {
    cout << "Before" << endl;   
    w();
    cout << "After" << endl;    
});
```

Comment: What is this `move`  you are calling; when I tried it, I got a pile of ambiguous overloads found by ADL.  Maybe I shouldn't have free move function in global namespace, or maybe you shoud std.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont or someone should not use `using namespace std` in global scope, more than one of those things had happened and they are mentioned as UB. but that's `std::move` from C++11, yet this syntax may work only in C++14 compliant compiler

Comment: `cout` and `endl` require qualificators.  Their absesne at least hints that somewhere there is `using` and I really hope it's not `using namespace`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/8nNQzS223bCI8LDg

Comment: @swift Oh, I also have a cout in the global namespace.  It composes emails to random people in my address book.  I assume that is what is used here.